# Rails 4 - controller strong params - generated with scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I use scaffolding generators to make my resources starting points.

I'm noticing, when I ask questions on this board, that people comment on the form of my strong params definitions in the controllers.

The scaffold generator creates them this format:

```
def industry_params
      params[:industry].permit(:sector, :icon)
end
```

Most resources that show how to whitelist strong params, show this format.

```
def industry_params
  params.require(:industry).permit(:sector, :icon)
end
```

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Is there anything wrong with the way the rails scaffold generator creates this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **require** method ensures that a specific parameter is present, and if it's not provided, the require method throws an error. It returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` for the key passed into require.

The **permit** method returns a copy of the parameters object, returning only the permitted keys and values.

As you can see while using scafffold's default system we need to check for is there is any value in the `params`, whereas **require** throw an error if its missing.

Comment: Hi Emu, the first variation (that's created by the scaffold) doesn't use the word require - so is your comment suggesting that somehow it is implied or something into the version created by scaffold generator? I'm afraid I don't understand the distinction as a difference between the two versions of the method.

Comment: In the first process it will only assume that you will get attributes in `params[:industry]` but if it not present, then you have to check it using `params[:industry].present?`, but in the 2nd system if `params[:industry]` is not present it'll throw an error. That's the basic difference.

Comment: Ok, so if im happy not to get an error message when a table doesn't have any saved attributes, then I'm fine to stick with the scaffold generator style?

Comment: Yes. But it would be safer to use the 2nd approach.